# How do I animate React Navigation transitions using createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, react-navigation, react-native-reanimated-v2

I've spent the last day trying to find out how to implement a simple fade screen transition with react-navigation but I cannot find one way to make it work with a bottom-tab-navigator. Can someone help me out? I've read the docs extensively but animations only seem to be available with a stack navigator.

Can you make transitions work on this snack demo?

https://snack.expo.io/?platform=android&name=Native%20Stack%20Navigator%20%7C%20React%20Navigation&dependencies=%40expo%2Fvector-icons%40*%2C%40react-native-community%2Fmasked-view%40*%2Creact-native-gesture-handler%40*%2Creact-native-pager-view%40*%2Creact-native-paper%40%5E4.7.2%2Creact-native-reanimated%40*%2Creact-native-safe-area-context%40*%2Creact-native-screens%40*%2Creact-native-tab-view%40%5E3.0.0%2C%40react-navigation%2Fbottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fdrawer%406.1.3%2C%40react-navigation%2Felements%401.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-bottom-tabs%406.0.4%2C%40react-navigation%2Fmaterial-top-tabs%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative-stack%406.0.5%2C%40react-navigation%2Fnative%406.0.2%2C%40react-navigation%2Fstack%406.0.6&hideQueryParams=true&sourceUrl=https%3A%2F%2Freactnavigation.org%2Fexamples%2F6.x%2Ftab-based-navigation-minimal.js

Comment: If my answer was helpful, please share your feedback.

Comment: It was, thank you. I just don't have enough reputation to give votes yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just create an `Animated.View` and attach that to your screens.

```
const FadeHomeScreen = (props) => (
  <FadeInView>
    <HomeScreen {...props} />
  </FadeInView>
);
```

then use this for `Tab.Screen`

```
<Tab.Screen name="Home" component={FadeHomeScreen} />
```

and just add `unmountOnBlur: true` in the `screenOptions`

```
const screenOptions = {
    unmountOnBlur: true,
    headerShown: false,
};

<Tab.Navigator {...{ screenOptions }}>
```

**Code:** https://snack.expo.dev/@fanish/native-stack-navigator-%7C-react-navigation

You could also use `react-native-reanimated` to create `<FadeInView />` component

Comment: Thank you so much. However, is there a way to maintain state on the faded page? Enabling unmountOnBlur causes the user to lose all navigation history. Is there an approach that enables the same behavior but retains all state logic?

Comment: Yes, there is a way to do that but you will have to use `focus` event listener. [Triggering an action with a 'focus' event listener](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/#triggering-an-action-with-a-focus-event-listener) and call `FadeAnimation`.

Comment: made it work using useFocusEffect hook https://snack.expo.dev/@pedrosousa/fade-animation-between-bottom-tabs. Now the next step is actually implementing a fade animation that transitions between screen contents and not between a rootviewbackground (in this case a blank white screen)

Comment: Add this property 
`<Tab.Navigator {...{ screenOptions,sceneContainerStyle }}>` 
and 
`const sceneContainerStyle={ backgroundColor:'#95a5a6' }`
You won't see the white screen.

Comment: Thank you man! You saved me bunch of time

Comment: why do you set unnmountOnBlur to true exactly?

Comment: This is a late reply, but @VariabileAleatoria, it is most likely due to the fact that when a navigation screen mounts it does not unmount until the app is closed. Thus `unmountOnBlur` is required for triggering the fade-out animation on un-mount so that it can fade back in on re-mount. I assume something similar could be implemented using React Navigation's `useFocusEffect` or attaching a listener to the navigation object.