# How can you add slide transition when switching between tabs on React Bottom Tab Navigator?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am using React Native with bottom tabs doing switches between native-stack tab screens.  For the most part it is okay, but the tab switch is a bit jarring and sometimes gets a bit laggy for more complex screens.

How do I introduce some form of transition when I click on the different tabs so it does not appear as jarring?

I know about [How do I animate React Navigation transitions using createBottomTabNavigator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227294/how-do-i-animate-react-navigation-transitions-using-createbottomtabnavigator) but that is done through fade animation.  What I am looking for is specifically a slide transition with each screen being native stack navigators.

Comment: Have you come across this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69227294/how-do-i-animate-react-navigation-transitions-using-createbottomtabnavigator

Comment: yes I am looking specifically for slide transition which is a bit more difficult because the tabs screens are isolated components

Answer (score 1):

try wrapping the screen with `<Animated.View>`

and styling transform for animation sliding

for ex:

```js
<Animated.View // Special animatable View
  style={{
    flex: 1,
    opacity: fadeAnim,

    transform: [{
      translateX: fadeAnim.interpolate({
        inputRange:[0,1],
        outputRange: [SCREEN_WIDTH,1],
        extrapolate:'clamp'
      })
    }],
    // Bind opacity to animated value
  }}>
  {props.children}
</Animated.View>
```

screen width you can get from Dimension

```
const SCREEN_WIDTH = Dimensions.get('window').width
```

or u can customize sliding for vertical with Dimension height

Comment: would this not cause problems with Native Headers and ScrollView/FlatList since it expects the top level of the screen to be a ScrollView/FlatList?